# How do I calculate Java HTTPGET bandwidth usage?

Tags: java, bandwidth, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have an application which is downloading pictures and I'm trying to manage the bandwidth it's using.

Used:

- JDK 1.7
- Apache HttpClient

I'm loading the pictures with that:

```
client = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);
client.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, new Integer(15000));
client.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, new Integer(15000));
client.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.TCP_NODELAY, false);

....

HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget, new BasicHttpContext());
System.exit(0);

....
```

Then using an HttpGet methode, I'm loading http://www.iconki.com/icons/System/16x16-Network-and-Security/earth.png (as an example).

Here is the issue.

Knowing that this image is 1K, I should expect the bandwidth usage to be 1K + some headers and extra packets. However, even if I'm not fully retrieving the content and exiting just after the method execution, I still have a 6K bandwidth usage. Does it mean there is always a 6K overhead for each HttpGet method called? I tried to loop in the client execution.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    httpget = new HttpGet(URL); 
    setMethodeHeaders(httpget);
    response = client.execute(httpget, new BasicHttpContext());
    httpget.abort();
    Thread.sleep (1000);
    System.out.println ("Looping...");
}
```

I got a 60K usage. That's HUGE for a 10k image. If I get the content-lenght, I have the 1K result. Not the 6K one.

So the questions are:

- **Is there a way to track real HttpClient bandwidth usage?**
- **Is there a way to reduce this overhead?**

Comment: How are you measuring your bandwidth usage?

Comment: That's not a 10K image you are transferring.  It is one 1K image ten times.  BIG difference.  (Try it with a real 10K image and see.)  You are also forcing the HTTP connection to close after each image which is making things worse.

Comment: @ams: I'm using WinPCap and NetWorx.

Comment: @StephenC: 10K is becaause of the loop ;) 10 times 1K image is like a 10K image. For the abort it's because I don't even want to get the image content. I just want to initiate the get and see the size of it. I tried with www.amazon.com/robots.txt and the result is the same. I always have 6K for the execution. Then if I consume the result I have the total usage + 6K.